Sort an area in Google Sheets
I'm looking for a way to sort an area in Google Sheets using script
When sorting, 2 rows should always be grouped and then sorted by column B. Can someone help me please?
I have this

COLUMN A    COLUMN B

Porsche     | 11
green       | 11
Mercedes    | 8
green       | 8
Ford        | 10
red         | 10


I want this:

Mercedes    | 8
green       | 8
Ford        | 10
red         | 10
Porsche     | 11
green       | 11


You could try this formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
  SORT(
    {A2:A, B2:B, IF(MOD(ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1, 2) = 0, B2:B, OFFSET(B2:B, 1, 0))},
    3, TRUE
  ),"Select Col1,Col2")
)



Thank you for your help, but I get an error:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4SPJmomPZHsbr18PAhMx9ETreTtfCFUeiP7hQB4PSs/edit?usp=sharing
